# Prevent Emacs from opening a buffer in a new frame

Tags: emacs, buffer, frames, menubar

I usually work switching between several buffers; and I usually choose another buffer to move to with `C-x b <name of buffer>`.  This is fine.  But if I choose a buffer from the "Buffers" menu, then it opens in a new frame, which I don't want.  How do I prevent Emacs from opening a buffer in a new frame - is this menubar behaviour, or buffers behaviour?

I'm using:

```
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars)
of 2014-03-08 on lamiak, modified by Debian
```

in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: By "frame", you probably mean a "window" in Emacspeak.

Comment: What is the value of `menu-bar-select-buffer-function`? (Find out via `C-h v menu-bar-select-buffer-function RET`.) I'm running Emacs 24.3 as well, and for me it is `switch-to-buffer` which displays buffers in the selected window (which seems to be the behavior you want).

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: Do you see this behavior when you start from `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file until you find the culprit code. That is quick to do. That's the general way to proceed. In this case, perhaps you will discover that your init file is just setting `menu-bar-select-buffer-function` or something, but it is still the way to go, to find where you are shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Many thanks - it turns out I'd enabled `menu-bar+` which redefines several variables, including `menu-bar-select-buffer-function`.  So I redefined that variable right back with a `setq` statement.  And now it's all fine.

Answer (score 1):

The function that is run when you click "Buffers" followed by the name of an open buffer is controlled by a variable called `menu-bar-select-buffer-function`. You are either modifying this variable directly in your `.emacs` file or you are using an add-on package that redefines it: By default, `menu-bar-select-buffer-function` is set to `switch-to-buffer`, which

> Display(s) buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME in the selected window.

This seems to be the behavior you want, so adding a simple

```
(setq menu-bar-select-buffer-function 'switch-to-buffer)
```

to your `.emacs` file should do the trick.